# What is the effect of having a static struct from C imported into Objective-C?

Tags: c, objective-c, inheritance, struct, static-variables

I'm debugging a legacy app and have encountered the following scenario

```
LegacySource.h
cFunctionModifyingSomeVariable()

LegacySource.c
static struct someVariable; //a custom struct


ObjectiveCImplementation.m
#import LegacySource.h
-(void)workWithLegacy {
   cFunctionModifyingSomeVariable(); // modifies variable declared in C class
}
```

**What is the effect of having a static struct from C imported into Objective-C?**

Do all of my Objective-C classes share the same single instance of the static struct, or does every instance get their own? In other words, if I make 3 instances of ObjectiveCImplementation, would they modify the same variable, or would their effects be independent from each other?

Comment: FYI - the answer is no different than including `LegacySource.h` into any number of the .c files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Objective-C code is not working with `someVariable`, at all. It's just calling a function. The static struct is not "imported" into Objective-C, whatever that might mean.

In any case, the variable `someVariable` is singular. There's just one such variable. No matter from where `cFunctionModifyingSomeVariable()` is called, it still just works with that one variable. That C function does not know about instances of an Objective-C class or, more generally, anything about its callers, so its behavior can't differ based on that.

Comment: Thank you! Would removing the static from the variable cause multiple instances of Objective-C to stop interfering with each other by modifying  a single variable?

Comment: No. A non-static file-scope variable is still singular; it's just that it has external linkage. That means that it can be accessed directly by code in modules other than LegacySource.c (if they declare it). Also, variables with external linkage are, effectively, in a global name space, so without `static` it might start to have name collisions with other variables of the same name with external linkage.

Comment: To make it so that different objects don't interfere with each other, you're going to have to make the C API object-oriented-ish. For example, consider the various Core Foundation types, like `CFArray` or `CFDictionary`. Those are still C APIs, but each function takes a parameter indicating which object it should operate on.

Comment: I will investigate bringing the objects into C functions through function parameters, or simply move the logic from C class into objective-c implementation file, if possible.